# Ищу бесплатное API для перевода более миллиона символов в сутки на русский

Tags: перевод, поиск-api

Пишу парсер, в котором необходимо переводить определенные поля с турецкого на русский. Я использовал переводчик от Яндекса. Там ограничение в 1 000 000 символов в сутки. Посмотрел на Google, там вроде ограничение в 1 млрд символов. Есть другие аналоги и бесплатные?

Comment: Я не думаю, что вы сможете найти такого же качества и более халявные. Подумайте в сторону "несколько разных api как один большой"

Comment: Наподобие использовать 100 разных аккаунтов?

Comment: Или использование разных поставщиков услуги. Тот же яндекс + гугл.

Comment: @ArchDemon только мне интересно, есть ли API у обычного переводчика Google а не облачного

Comment: Писал программу, которая использовала api яндекс переводчика с английского на русский. Перевод самый ужасный, который я видел. Даже школьник лучше переведет. Советую дважды подумать, прежде чем использовать сервисы яндекс.

Comment: https://fasttranslator.herokuapp.com